# IndexError: Too many indices in array python numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn

I am creating an export for a classifier model and some rescaling values. With the guidance of a PhD student that studies the field, he provided me with code that creates a rescaling dictionary for us to use. 
The relevant code:

```
PROBA_RESCALING_N_SAMPLES = 100
PROBA_RESCALING_WINDOW_RADIUS = 0.05
y_proba = classifier.predict_proba(x)
y_proba_rescaling = {proba: y[np.abs(y_proba - proba) <= PROBA_RESCALING_WINDOW_RADIUS].mean() for proba in np.linspace(0, 1, PROBA_RESCALING_N_SAMPLES)}
```

The error occurs at the last line, and it says:

> IndexError: too many indices for array

I looked over the forums here for some answers,and sat with a friend for over an hour and still I couldn't understand why that error was caused. Yesterday the code seemed fine, and suddenly today it is bugged.

EDIT : I have missed a couple of important details that I forgot to mention:
1. the Y variable is an array that contains zeros and ones, it represents the Y axis in my dataset for the ML learning.
2. I have narrowed down the problem to the `y[np.abs(y_proba - proba) <= PROBA_RESCALING_WINDOW_RADIUS]` part. Running it on its own produces the error.

Comment: The only indexing in that line is `y[...]`.  Why haven't you told us anything about that array?  Information other arrays/variables in the expression might help.  Better yet, provide a minimal example that generates the error.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have corrected my mistakes and I hope it will be more understandable.

Comment: What is the `shape` of `y`?  What does `np.abs(y_proba - proba) <= PROBA_RESCALING_WINDOW_RADIUS` produce? (shape, dtype)?

Answer (score 0):

```
y[np.abs(y_proba - proba) <= PROBA_RESCALING_WINDOW_RADIUS]
```

Do you mean:

```
y[np.abs(y_proba - proba)] <= PROBA_RESCALING_WINDOW_RADIUS
```

Where the bracket spot changed? You are indexing  a comparison in Y list. It doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: No, Im indexing a boolean. The comparsion returns a value - True or False.

Comment: You should Try to print each of the parts of the comparison and see what they give you. They can't be just a number... Try doing : print(np.abs(y_proba - proba)) and print(PROBA_RESCALING_WINDOW_RADIUS), and come back with the result.